# NextJS - Custom Image Loader Always Return Largest Width?

Tags: next.js

Note: Im using NextJS 12.

I've a file named CustomImagePath and Its like that:

```
const customImagePath = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
    return `https://myimage.com/${src}?width=${width}`
}

export default customImagePath
```

And Im using it like

```
        <Image loader={customImagePath}
            width={expectedWidth}
            height={expectedHeight}
            priority={true}
            layout={`responsive`}
            src={`/${expectedWidth+'x'+expectedHeight}${src}`}
        />
```

And my next.config.js

```
images: {
  deviceSizes: [320, 640, 660, 768, 1024, 1600],
```

My expectation is;
loader will receive width by current device width.
But it doesnt. It always return width as 1600. Even I'm working on a small screen or large screen. It doesnt send me resized values or options.

How should I handle that?